# Не получается сделать обновление списка recyclerView при достижении top или bottom

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

У меня есть вопрос по этой проблеме - [Как правильно реализовать бесконечную прокрутку recyclerview на подобии gmail?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/923675/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-recyclerview-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B8-gmail). Но у меня после большого кол-ва попыток не получилось подключить библиотеку от гугла для обновления данных, поэтому я начал делать через всякие костыли. Все почти работает но не совсем так как нужно. В адаптере в функции `onBindViewHolder`:

```
if (position == getItemCount() - 1 && position != getItemCount() && getItemCount() / 50 > 0) {
            onBottomReachedListener.onBottomReached(position);
            Log.w("MY_TAG", "Load more from bottom of list");
        }

        if (position == 0 && reached) {
            onTopReachedListener.onTopReached(position);
            Log.w("MY_TAG", "Load more from top of list");
        }
```

суть в том чтобы слушатели достижения начала и конца списка работали только при наличии >50 элементов. Частично получилось обновить данные при достижении конца списка, но дальше не получается. Что именно у меня не получается - при достижении конца списка мне нужно добавить данные в список, которые берутся с сервера, и отобразить их. В этой части у меня все нормально,  данные при достижении конца списка грузятся нормально, но дальше я ставлю условие что конец списка был достижен и можно загрузить данные при достижении начала списка, и дальше у меня проблемы. После того как я загрузил данные при достижении нижней границы списка у меня в обновленном списке адаптер получает position 0 и начинает грузить данные а так не должно быть, я не знаю как это реализовать. Вот в главном активити у меня есть слушатели:

```
((ListAdapter) adapter).setOnBottomReachedListener(new OnBottomReachedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onBottomReached(int position) {
                                Log.w("MY_TAG", "reach the end of list" + " " + String.valueOf(((ListAdapter) adapter).get()));
                                ListAdapter.setReached(true);
                                getMessages(type, a_token, offset + 50);
                                setOffset(getOffset() + 50);
                                setOnBottom(true);
                            }
                        });


                        ((ListAdapter) adapter).setOnTopReachedListener(new OnTopReachedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onTopReached(int position) {
                                Log.w("MY_TAG", "reach the start of list" + " " + String.valueOf(((ListAdapter) adapter).get() + " " + String.valueOf(onBottom)));

                                ListAdapter.setReached(false);
                                getMessages(type, a_token, getOffset());
                                setOffset(getOffset() - 50);
                            }
                        });
```

мне нужно сделать какое-то условие которое позволит мне дойти до конца списка, заполнить его новыми данными, и дальше только при попытке пользователя потянуть список вниз заполнить его данными с пред. пакета данных, а не делать это автоматически из-за проверки. Возможно я очено путанно объяснил, но надеюсь что решение лежит на поверхности.

Comment: Сталкивался с подобным, было сделано на обычном ListView. Если память не подводит, то называется пагинация.

Comment: @V.March, а как сделать пагинацию без либы, а то я пробовал внедрить эту библиотеку в свой адаптер и не получилось :(

Answer (score 1):

Возможно Вам нужно что-то типа этого применить.

Здесь реализована проверка на достижение конца списка. Количество элементов всего и количество видимых элементов и позиция первого видимого элемента. И исходя из соотношений значений можно подбирать нужные действия.

В этом примере реализовано запуск анимаций (прятанье или показ `Fab`). У Вас же это будет подгрузка нового пакета данных.

```
private ListView listTablesView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    listTablesView = findViewById(R.id.list_table);

    listTablesView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                             int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            boolean loadMore = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount;

            if (loadMore && (visibleItemCount) < totalItemCount) {
                fab.animate().translationY(fab.getHeight() + fab_bottomMargin).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();
            } else {
                fab.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

А так же очень хороший [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473933/android-listview-setonscrolllistener) на EN.SO.